# vb.net Legend Marker Size

Tags: vb.net, charts, event-handling

In a Form called ChartSmile, I want to increase the size of the markers in the legend.  This code doesn't do anything, what am I missing?

```
Public Event CustomizeLegend As EventHandler(Of CustomizeLegendEventArgs)

Private Sub ChartSmile_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler CustomizeLegend, AddressOf Chart1_CustomizeLegend
End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_CustomizeLegend(sender As Object, _
                               e As CustomizeLegendEventArgs) Handles Me.CustomizeLegend
    For Each item In e.LegendItems
        item.MarkerSize = 50
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of chart is it?  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.legenditem.markersize(v=vs.110).aspx) states 'that markers will not be applied to data points of pie, doughnut and any stacked chart types.'

Comment: Hey, it's a Spline chart.  There are markers in the chart and I can control their size.  Ther are also markers in the legend, but you can't control the marker size within properties.

Comment: You can increase the font size of the Legend to increase the size of the marker but that also increases the size of the legend text. It doesn't look like the legend markersize properties work as we'd expect. In [this post] (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6653be8c-fdc0-46c2-95f2-8ef39025fd1c/how-to-change-the-marker-size-of-the-legend?forum=MSWinWebChart) it suggests you can add a custom image to the legend's CustomItems collection to get bigger images.